# How to turn on a module with a pulse

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, transistors, power, module

I have some issue turning on the module Quectel BG600-ML3. Here are the instructions given in the data sheet :

[image]

The PWRKEY must be taken high for 500-1000ms. I can only affect the MCU_PWRKEY (Turn on pulse on the schematic). I believe that my error is sending the pulse wanted on the mcu_pwrkey and that it doesn't transfer identically to the pwrkey. Here's my code :

```
#include "wiring_private.h" // pinPeripheral() function

int MCU_PWRKEY = 12;
//PA15 PIN 16 D12


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(MCU_PWRKEY, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(MCU_PWRKEY, LOW);
    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(MCU_PWRKEY, HIGH);
    delay(750);
    digitalWrite(MCU_PWRKEY, LOW);
    delay(5000);
    

}
```

With my code, the module doesn't turn on (as the leds show). Any help would be much appreciated !
Thank you in advance =)

Comment: What is a 'pule'?

Comment: Sorry @Transistor, pulse*